# How to find last column with value (for each row), with some rows with all NA as values?

Tags: r, dataframe

I was having the same problem as [How to find last column with value (for each row) in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65524144/14021430), except I have rows with no value (entire row of NA). The sample provided in said post did not have an entire row of NAs.

I was wondering how I should modify the following? I do not want to remove those rows with all NAs because they will be useful in later analysis.

```
df %>%
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(m = {tmp <- c_across(starts_with('m'))
               tail(na.omit(tmp), 1)}) %>%
  ungroup
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Wouldn't this option from that similar question work? It would return the ID field, if everything else is NA:  `names(df)[-1][max.col(!is.na(df[-1]), 'last')]`.  If you don't, I think the easiest route would be to add an index field (like id), and that will allow you to identify rows with all NA, too.

Answer (score 3):

If all the elements in the rows are empty, then a general solution would be to create condition to return `NA` for those rows

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(m = {tmp <- c_across(starts_with('m'))
               if(all(is.na(tmp))) NA_character_ else 
                   tail(na.omit(tmp), 1)}) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 5
     id m_1   m_2   m_3   m    
  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1 a     e     i     i    
2     2 b     <NA>  <NA>  b    
3     3 <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> 
4     4 d     h     l     l
```

---

If the OP wants to return only the last single non-NA element, we may also add an index `[1]` to extract, which automatically return `NA` when there are no elements

```
df %>%
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(m = {tmp <- c_across(starts_with('m'))
               tail(na.omit(tmp), 1)[1]}) %>%
  ungroup
# A tibble: 4 × 5
     id m_1   m_2   m_3   m    
  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1 a     e     i     i    
2     2 b     <NA>  <NA>  b    
3     3 <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> 
4     4 d     h     l     l
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4), m_1 = c("a", "b", NA, "d"), 
    m_2 = c("e", NA, NA, "h"), m_3 = c("i", NA, NA, "l")), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @akrun, this runs beautifully! Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3):

Using data from @akrun (many thanks) we could do maybe this way:

`'\\b[^,]+$'` is a regular expression:

`\\` ... means escape (in other words do not match) this is `R` special in other languages it is only one `\`

`\\b`... The metacharacter \b is an anchor like `^` and `$` sign. It matches at a position that is called a “word boundary”. This match is zero-length.

`[^,]+`... stands for character class, here special with the `^`caret: One character that is not `,`. The `+` means here one or more `,`

`$` ... means end of string or end of line depending on multiline mode.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("m"), ~case_when(!is.na(.) ~ cur_column()), .names = 'new_{col}')) %>%
  unite(New_Col, starts_with('new'), na.rm = TRUE, sep = ', ') %>% 
  mutate(New_Col = str_extract(New_Col, '\\b[^,]+$'))
```

```
  id  m_1  m_2  m_3 New_Col
1  1    a    e    i     m_3
2  2    b <NA> <NA>     m_1
3  3 <NA> <NA> <NA>    <NA>
4  4    d    h    l     m_3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sorry I am not quite experienced in R, but I was wondering what '\\b[^,]+$' does please?

Comment: Please see my update.

Answer (score 2):

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4), m_1 = c("a", NA, "c", "d"), m_2 = c("e", NA, "g", "h"), m_3 = c("i", NA, NA, "l"))


df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    nms = list(str_subset(names(df), "^m")),
    m = c_across(starts_with("m")) %>%
      {
        ifelse(test = all(is.na(.)),
          yes = NA,
          no = nms[which(. == tail(na.omit(.), 1))]
        )
      }
  ) %>%
  select(-nms)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 5
#> # Rowwise: 
#>      id m_1   m_2   m_3   m    
#>   <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1     1 a     e     i     m_3  
#> 2     2 <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> 
#> 3     3 c     g     <NA>  m_2  
#> 4     4 d     h     l     m_3




# only the value no the column name
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    m = c_across(starts_with("m")) %>%
      {
        ifelse(test = all(is.na(.)),
          yes = NA,
          no = tail(na.omit(.), 1)
        )
      }
  )
#> # A tibble: 4 × 5
#> # Rowwise: 
#>      id m_1   m_2   m_3   m    
#>   <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1     1 a     e     i     i    
#> 2     2 <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> 
#> 3     3 c     g     <NA>  g    
#> 4     4 d     h     l     l
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>